# jQuery .get url and use .each on data

Tags: jquery

I am receiving the html using the jQuery get function.  This works.

```
    $.get(searchlink, function(data){
        $("#results").text(data);
    });
```

Now the question - I would like to use the .each jQuery function to iterate through each div contained in *data*.  Specifically I would like to target a single div in data, then iterate through the multiple div inside using .each.
What is the proper syntax to connect *data* to the .each function?

Example content of *data*:

```
    <div id="targetID">
       <div>content</div>
       <div>content</div>
       ....
       <div>content</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

EDIT:
Let's elaborate step by step what is needed for an answer:
1.) I get the page contents of an html page, and call it *data*. (done)
2.) Get the content of specific div, which is targetID within *data*.
3.) Within targetID div, get the content of the outside divs, one at a time in order to pull individual content from these divs.

EDIT: Answer - this is how it is written after stumbling guessing the syntax.

```
   $(data).find('#targetID').find('div').each(function(){});
```

Comment: Convert it to a collection, then act upon it like any other jquery collection.

Comment: If you had that div in your html, how would you access it and loop over it's children? Why would you expect this scenario to be any different?

Comment: This was the question:
"What is the proper syntax to connect data to the .each function?"  
data (haystack of #targetID).each 'div' (function .... etc etc etc.
How is this syntactically written?
That was the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer after doing guesswork and combining oma's assistance:

```
$(data).find('#targetID').find('div').each(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a string and looks like `"<div>text<div>"` a valid html, you can use like this.

```
$(data).find("div")
```

This will return all the divs.

Comment: Is there a way to do this directly from the data string?

Comment: I updated the answer, but next time give this info, i can't guess if you want the data to be manipulated before or after appending it to the #result ...

Comment: "What is the proper syntax to connect data to the .each function?"
Nope, pretty much stated this.
Thanks for the help.